# How do I interpret a python byte string coming from F1 2020 game UDP packet?

Tags: endianness, packet, unsigned-integer, packed

Title may be wildly incorrect for what I'm trying to work out.

I'm trying to interpret packets I am recieving from a racing game in a way that I understand, but I honestly don't really know what I'm looking at, or what to search to understand it.
Information on the packets I am recieving here:
https://forums.codemasters.com/topic/54423-f1%C2%AE-2020-udp-specification/?tab=comments#comment-532560

I'm using python to print the packets, here's a snippet of the output, which I don't understand how to interpret.

> received message: b'\xe4\x07\x01\x03\x01\x07O\x90.\xea\xc2!7\x16\xa5\xbb\x02C\xda\n\x00\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x03:\x00\x00\x00 A\x00\x00\xdcB\xb5+\xc1@\xc82\xcc\x10\t\x00\xd9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$tJ\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01

I'm very new to coding, and not sure what my next step is, so a nudge in the right direction will help loads, thanks.

This is the python code:

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 20777
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
              socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print ("received message:", data)
```

Comment: Suggest renaming title to "How do I interpret a python byte string coming from a game?" Consider mentioning the title of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you link to is describing the data format. All data represented as a series of 1's and 0's. A byte is a series of 8 1's and 0's. However, just because you have a series of bytes doesn't mean you know how to interpret them. Do they represent a character? An integer? Can that integer be negative? All of that is defined by whoever crafted the data in the first place.

The type descriptions you see at the top are telling you how to actually interpret that series of 1's and 0's. When you see "unit8", that is an "unsigned integer that is 8 bits (1 byte) long". In other words, a positive number between 0 and 255. An "int8" on the other hand is an "8-bit integer", or a number that can be positive or negative (so the range is -128 to 127). The same basic idea applies to the *16 and *64 variants, just with 16 bits or 64 bits. A float represent a floating point number (a number with a fractional part, such as 1.2345), generally 4 bytes long. Additionally, you need to know the order to interpret the bytes within a word (left-to-right or right-to-left). This is referred to as the endianness, and every computer architecture has a native endianness (big-endian or little-endian).

Given all of that, you can interpret the PacketHeader. The easiest way is probably to use the `struct` package in Python. Details can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

As a proof of concept, the following will interpret the first 24 bytes:

```
import struct
data = b'\xe4\x07\x01\x03\x01\x07O\x90.\xea\xc2!7\x16\xa5\xbb\x02C\xda\n\x00\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x03:\x00\x00\x00 A\x00\x00\xdcB\xb5+\xc1@\xc82\xcc\x10\t\x00\xd9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$tJ\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'

#Note that I am only taking the first 24 bytes. You must pass data that is
#the appropriate length to the unpack function. We don't know what everything 
#else is until after we parse out the header
header = struct.unpack('<HBBBBQfIBB', data[:24])
print(header)
```

You basically want to read the first 24 bytes to get the header of the message. From there, you need to use the `m_packetId` field to determine what the rest of the message is. As an example, this particular packet has a packetId of 7, which is a "Car Status" packet. So you would look at the packing format for the `struct CarStatus` further down on that page to figure out how to interpret the rest of the message. Rinse and repeat as data arrives.

Update: In the format string, the `<` tells you to interpret the bytes as little-endian with no alignment (based on the fact that the documentation says it is little-endian and packed). I would recommend reading through the entire section on Format Characters in the documentation above to fully understand what all is happening regarding alignment, but in a nutshell it will try to align those bytes with their representation in memory, which may not match exactly the format you specify. In this case, `HBBBBQ` takes up 2 bytes more than you'd expect. This is because your computer will try to pack structs in memory so that they are word-aligned. Your computer architecture determines the word alignment (on a 64-bit computer, words are 64-bits, or 8 bytes, long). A `Q` takes a full word, so the packer will try to align everything before the Q to a word. However, `HBBBB` only requires 6 bytes; so, Python will, by default, pad an extra 2 bytes to make sure everything lines up. Using `<` at the front both ensures that the bytes will be interpreted in the correct order, and that it won't try to align the bytes.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. For clarification, how do you know the header will be 26 bytes? I'm a little confused about how many bytes the float m_sessionTime uses, as all the unsigned integers total 20 bytes, but there is no 6 byte float format ? It should total 24 bytes under the unpack format you used...
I'm not at all saying you've done something wrong by the way, just basically trying to find the first/last two bytes that makes the header a total of 26 bytes.

Comment: You actually brought up a really good point. I actually worked backwards on this, which gives us the right answer, but could actually be buggy. I'll amend my response, but in a nutshell I came up with the format string, then passed the full data to it. When python complained it needed to be 26 bytes, I took just the first 26 bytes and called it good =).

Answer (score 0):

Just for information if someone else is looking for this. In python there is the library [f1-2019-telemetry](https://f1-2019-telemetry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) existing. On the documentation, there is a missing part about the "how to use" so here is a snippet:

```
from f1_2020_telemetry.packets import *
...

udp_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind((host, port))

while True:
    udp_packet = udp_socket.recv(2048)
    packet = unpack_udp_packet(udp_packet)

    if isinstance(packet, PacketSessionData_V1):  # refer to doc for classes / attribute
        print(packet.trackTemperature) # for example
    if isinstance(packet, PacketParticipantsData_V1):
        for i, participant in enumerate(packet.participants):
            print(DriverIDs[participant.driverId]) # the library has some mapping for pilot name / track name / ...
```

Regards,

Nicolas